# Promise Redux : TypeError: next is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a little app running on React + Redux with redux-promise middleware in order to deal with promise API call. I would like to manage the state of each api call (loading, success & error). So, as [the official documentation says](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware/blob/master/docs/guides/custom-suffixes.md) I change the applyMiddleware argument.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import reducers from './reducers';
import routes from './routes';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  promiseMiddleware({
    promiseTypeSuffixes: ['LOADING', 'SUCCESS', 'ERROR'],
  }),
)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

But when I change the appyMiddleware my app doesn't work anymore, I have this error showing on console:

> TypeError: next is not a function

If I change back this line, everything works again as intended.

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware)(createStore); // App works again
```

What's wrong?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly believe that the way you create the store is incorrect.

In creating a store, there are 3 arguments,

```
createStore(reducer, preloadedState, enhancer) {...}
```

(1) reducer -> (required)

(2) preLoadedState -> (optional)

(3) enhancer -> (optional) // This is where your applyMiddleware should be passed. Hence, the minimal creation of a store is,

```
 const store = createStore(() => {});
```

To answer your question, creating a store with a middleware should be,

```
 const store = createStore(yourReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware))
```

or simply

```
  const store = createStore(yourReducer, applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware))
```

// This should also work because if the 2nd parameter is a function then it will be treated as the enhancer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately that doesn't solve the error :(